# Invalid Command for o365 spo login CLI

Tags: spfx, pnp, office-dev-pnp

I am setting Azure DevOps pipleline for my SharePoint framework project and followed below steps,

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52777.sharepoint-framework-how-to-implement-cicd.aspx?Sort=MostUseful&PageIndex=1

Everything was working and all of a sudden I am getting Invalid Command Error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per below the new command is "o365 login" and not "o365 spo login"

https://github.com/pnp/office365-cli/issues/889